# Finds the point of discontinuity of $x[x]$ and $[\sin{x}]$

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Find the points of discontinuity of $f(x)$ = $x[x]$ and $g(x)$=$[\sin{x}]$, where $[]$ stands for greatest integer function.

For $f(x)$, as we know that $[x]$ is discontinuous at integers therefore I tried to check if $f$ is discontinuous at integers. I determined the left-hand and right-hand limits of $f$ at $a$ (Say, $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb Z$), both are found to be different. The left-hand limit of $f$ at $a$ is $a(a-1)$ and right hand limit is $a^{2}$. Then f should be discontinuous at integers same as $[x]$ and if we take $a=0$ then it will be continuous at $0$ So $f(x)$ will be discontinuous at integers except $0$. But If I want to draw the graph of this function then I have to combine the graph of $x$ and $[x]$ (I guess?). And this graph is confusing me. Please correct me if I am wrong. Also, how can I confirm the same with the help of the graph?

For $g(x)$ I drew the graph of $\sin{x}$ and with its help, I drew the graph of $[\sin{x}]$ for [0, $4\pi$] and found that the points of discontinuities for this function are such as: $\pi/2$, $\pi$, $2\pi$, $5\pi/2$, $3\pi$,$4\pi$ then for $\mathbb R$, the set of points of discontinuities for $g(x)$ will be {$(4$n$-3)\pi/2$, $n\pi$ : $n\in\mathbb Z$}.But I am not completely sure if I am correct. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere. Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $a \le x < a+1$ for some integer $a$ then $f(x) = ax$, can you plot this for each integer $a$?

Comment: Oh, thanks! Now I understand how the graph will be.  So the graph starts with $0$, and goes on with integers, right?

Comment: In the expression for points of discontinuities of $g$, did you mean $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ instead of $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Oh yes! that's $\mathbb Z$, correcting it now. Thanks for mentioning it.